# Retrieving the elements of a matrix with negated exact indexing with index matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

For example I have `A=[11 24 33 47 52 67]` and I have indices matrix as `I = [2 3]` so I want to have the elements of A from the indices other than indices given with I. So I want to have `B = [11 47 52 67]`. How can I do it and use I as a negated indices matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go for

```
  idx = logical(ones(size(A)));   % // all indices here
```

or, as @Gunther Struyf suggests,

```
  idx = true(size(A));
```

then

```
  idx(I) = 0;                       % // excluding not desired indices    
  B = A(idx);                       % // selection
```

Alternatively

```
 B = A;
 B(I) = [];
```

Comment: you can use `true(...)` instead of `logical(ones(...))` ;) and `size` would be better than `length` imo, because it is more general

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) to exclude indices. Here's a one-liner for you:

```
B = A(setdiff(1:numel(A), I))
```