# Exclude elements from array

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a column vector:

```
A = [1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 5; 5; 7];
```

I wish to exclude the elements of `A` that are in a second matrix `B`:

```
B = [4; 5]
```

The final result should be:

```
A = [1; 2; 3; 7]
```

I am pretty sure using MATLAB elegant syntaxing, this be accomplished without writing a `for` loop, but not sure how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove elements at a set of indices in a vector in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789847/) and [Retrieving the elements of a matrix with negated exact indexing with index matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918790/)

Comment: Note that `'` is the (complex conjugate) transpose function. So you should use a different letter for your second matrix.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This is not a duplicate, I thought the second matrix holds indices to the rows to be removed, but it contains the elements themselves.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would use `Afilt=A(~ismember(A,B));`. This will return all elements of `A` which are not in `B`.

Comment: Alternatively:
`A(ismember(A,B))=[];`

Answer (score 6):

You can compare values with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
A = A(all(bsxfun(@ne, A(:), B(:).'), 2))
```

This approach is especially good if you need to handle floating-point numbers (where`ismember` fails):

```
A(all(abs(bsxfun(@minus, A(:), B(:).')) >= eps, 2))
```

Instead of [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), you can set any tolerance threshold you want.

Comment: If you want to preserve the order, use `setOrder`= `'stable'` as additional input

Comment: using setdiff you loose multiplicity of elements.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Absolutely correct, haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: If you want to remove row 4 and 5 it is this, if you want to remove the rows with fours and fives check the other answers.

Simple as this

```
A = [1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 5; 5; 7];     
B = [4; 5];

A(B)=[];
```

Comment: I think you got the question wrong (like I did). You are supposed to remove the values 4 and 5, not rows 4 and 5.

Comment: @EitanT I have edited accordingly. Not sure whether we misread or whether the information was added.

Comment: I think we were mislead by the wording of the question.